# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Fragment shader with multiple textures

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, fragment-shader

I'm setting up two textures as follow:

```
GLKTextureInfo  *texture = [GLKTextureLoader ...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "uTextureMask"), 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name);

texture = [GLKTextureLoader ...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "uTextureLabel"), 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.name);
```

referred in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D uTextureMask;
uniform sampler2D uTextureLabel;
```

The problem is that only the last texture I bind is available in the shader.
In the example above, only uTextureLabel works.

Any idea?

Thanks,
DAN

**UPDATE:**

glGetUniformLocation returns 13 for uTextureMask and 14 for uTextureLabel.

In the shader I do:

```
highp vec4 label = texture2D(uTextureLabel, vTexel);
highp vec4 mask = texture2D(uTextureMask, vTexel);

highp vec3 surface;

surface = label.rgb;
// surface = mask.rgb; // <--- DOESN'T WORK    

gl_FragColor = vec4(surface, 1.0);
```

Comment: Can you check the return values of the `glGetUniformLocation` calls? What you're doing in the code shown here looks fine to me. I noticed that you bind the same texture twice, but I figure you did that just to simplify the example.

Comment: sure! question updated with some details

Comment: I don't know how GLKit works, but it might be the case that the GLKTextureLoader stuff internally changes the texture binding. Since you call it while unit 0 is still active, it might destroy the binding you had on that unit previously.

Comment: Brilliant! I've moved glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1) one line up and it works. Thank you derhass.

Answer (score 0):

On IOS `GLKTextureLoader` not only load `PNG. It's also create texture name by`glGenTexture`, bind it and load data on GPU and also set default parametres for GL_WRAP_MODE and MIN/MAG algorithms.

In your code i see that you call

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(MaskTexture)
glBindTexture(LabelTature) // this call made GLKTextureLoader
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
glBindTexture(LabelTexture)
```

In result you have `LabelTexture` binded into `GL_TEXTURE0` and `GL_TEXTURE1` texture blocks.